# Simple Stored Procedure in Sql Server: Inserting into Bridge Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue with the below stored procedure. It runs fine as long as I don't uncomment the last insert INSERT. If I were to uncomment the last INSERT, I get the following error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure
>   InsertRecipeWithTags, Line 42 The
>   INSERT statement conflicted with the
>   FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Tag_TagRecipe". The conflict
>   occurred in database "RecipeBox",
>   table "RecipeDetails.Tag", column
>   'tagID'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

For clarification, I have three tables:

```
recipe(id, title, introduction, directions)
recipeTag(id, recipeID, tagID)
tag(id, name)
```

So if I try to insert into the `recipeTag` table I get the above error. Please advise.

Thanks.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [RecipeDetails].[InsertRecipeWithTags]
/*
    variables that map to columns
*/
@title varchar(50),
@intro varchar(255),
@directions varchar(2200),
@ingredients varchar(2200),
@difficulty varchar(6), /*need check constraint setting difficulty to "beginner" "medium" or "expert"*/
@prepTimeHour tinyint,
@prepTimeMinute tinyint,
@inactiveTimeHour tinyint,
@inactiveTimeMinute tinyint,
@servings tinyint,
@photo varbinary(MAX),
@tagName varchar(50),
@tagdescription varchar(255)

AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @RecipeID int, @TagID int

    INSERT INTO RecipeDetails.Recipe (title, intro,directions, ingredients, difficulty, 
    prepTimeHour, prepTimeMinute, inactiveTimeHour, inactiveTimeMinute, servings, photo)
    VALUES (@title, @intro,@directions, @ingredients, @difficulty, @prepTimeHour, @prepTimeMinute,
    @inactiveTimeHour, @inactiveTimeMinute, @servings, @photo)

    SELECT @RecipeID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    SELECT * FROM RecipeDetails.Recipe WHERE recipeID = @RecipeID;

    INSERT INTO RecipeDetails.Tag (name, description)
    VALUES (@tagName, @tagdescription)

    SELECT @TagID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    SELECT * FROM RecipeDetails.Tag WHERE tagID = @TagID;

    /*INSERT INTO RecipeDetails.TagRecipe (tagID, recipeID)
    VALUES (@RecipeID, @TagID)*/
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the order?

```
INSERT INTO RecipeDetails.TagRecipe (tagID, recipeID)
VALUES (@TagID, @RecipeID)
```

You had then the wrong way around

Comment: That's it! Thanks! I'm still a very new to this stuff and that was helpful!